# How can I verify if a cell is occupied in Java?

Tags: java, game-development

I am, with other people, working on a Java project which consists in a strategy turn-based game set on a board with square cells (like a chess board), where two armies fight until one of the generals dies.
The troops' position consists in two int variables X and Y, and the player can move every troop by selecting it and clicking on a compass with right directions ([N](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/north#Noun), [S](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/south#Noun), [E](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/east#Noun), [W](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/west#Noun), [NE](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/north-east#Noun), [NW](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/northwest#Noun), [SE](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/southeast#Noun), and [SW](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/southwest#Noun)) and the troop moves n squares depending on the Mov attribute every troop has.

```
public void move(int direction) {
    int currentX = getX();
    int currentY = getY();
    int movement = getMov();
    int newX, newY; 

    switch (direction) {
        case 1: // nw
            newX = currentX - movement;
            newY = currentY - movement;
            break;
        case 2: // north
            newX = currentX;
            newY = currentY - movement;
            break;
        case 3: // ne
            newX = currentX + movement;
            newY = currentY - movement;
            break;
        case 4: // east
            newX = currentX + movement;
            newY = currentY;
            break;
        case 5: // se
            newX = currentX + movement;
            newY = currentY + movement;
            break;
        case 6: // south
            newX = currentX;
            newY = currentY + movement;
            break;
        case 7: // sw
            newX = currentX - movement;
            newY = currentY + movement;
            break;
        case 8: // west
            newX = currentX - movement;
            newY=currentY;
            break;
        default:
            // errore
            break;
    }

    // verify if the position is valid


    if (isValidMove(newX, newY)) {
        setPosition(newX, newY);
        setSta(getSta() - 1);
    } else {
        // not a valid move
    }

    private boolean isValidMove(int newX, int newY) {
        if (newX < 0 || newX > 14 || newY < 0 || newY > 14) {
            //out of the field
            return false;

        }else {
            for (/*every other troop*/) {
                if (otherTroops.getX() == newX && otherTroops.getY() == newY) {
                //occupied cell
                return false;
                }
            }
        }

        if(getSta() < 1){
            //no stamina
            return false;
            
        } else {
            // move is valid
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

When a troop moves, the game makes various checks in order to verify if the move is "legal" or not, like checking if the target cell is inside the board itself.

One check I've been stuck in for a while is the one who doesn't allow the move if the target cell is already occupied, how can I make that?

As you can see, one idea I had was to make a for cycle and checking the new position coordinates for every other troop in the board, but I don't have any idea on how to implement that. Any suggestion?

Comment: Unless moves can happen in parallel, it would be faster to assign a state to each cell (occupied/free) and just check the state of target cell. Of course this assumes the state must be maintained accordingly (free up when moving from/occupy when moving to).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.

I would suggest using a multidimensional array.

*[Arrays (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)*.

> *"You can also declare an array of arrays (also known as a multidimensional array) by using two or more sets of brackets, such as String[][] names. Each element, therefore, must be accessed by a corresponding number of index values."*

> *"In the Java programming language, a multidimensional array is an array whose components are themselves arrays. ..."*

Here is an example of a basic chess board implementation.

Use *enum* objects as a way to define each piece, on the board.

```java
enum Pieces {
    ROOK_1, KNIGHT_1, BISHOP_1, KING, QUEEN, BISHOP_2,  KNIGHT_2, ROOK_2,
    PAWN_1, PAWN_2, PAWN_3, PAWN_4, PAWN_5, PAWN_6, PAWN_7, PAWN_8
}

enum Team {
    BLACK, WHITE
}
```

And, a class to contain each piece, collectively.
This can be a nested class—that's why it's static, here.

```java
static class Piece {
    Pieces piece;
    Team team;

    Piece(Pieces piece, Team team) {
        this.piece = piece;
        this.team = team;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return piece.name().substring(0, 1);
    }
}
```

Then, you can then use a multidimensional array, of *Piece*, to represent the game board.

```java
Piece[][] board = new Piece[8][8];
```

Additionally, use a method to populate the array, initially.

```java
void set() {
    int indexA = 0, indexB = 0;
    for (Pieces piece : Pieces.values()) {
        board[indexA][indexB] = new Piece(piece, BLACK);
        board[indexA == 1 ? 6 : 7][indexB++] = new Piece(piece, WHITE);
        if (piece == ROOK_2) {
            indexA++;
            indexB = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You can utilize a *getXY* method, to return the current *board* value.

```java
Piece getXY(int x, int y) {
    return board[x][y];
}
```

Finally, you're *isValidMove* would simply require a check to *board*, for an empty space, or a piece from the opposite team.

```java
boolean isValidMove(int x, int y, Team team) {
    if (board[x][y] == null) return true;
    else return board[x][y].team != team;
}
```

Here is the entire code.

```java
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = new Example();
        example.set();

        System.out.println(example);
    }

    Piece[][] board = new Piece[8][8];

    Piece getXY(int x, int y) {
        return board[x][y];
    }

    boolean isValidMove(int x, int y, Team team) {
        if (board[x][y] == null) return true;
        else return board[x][y].team != team;
    }

    void set() {
        int indexA = 0, indexB = 0;
        for (Pieces piece : Pieces.values()) {
            board[indexA][indexB] = new Piece(piece, BLACK);
            board[indexA == 1 ? 6 : 7][indexB++] = new Piece(piece, WHITE);
            if (piece == ROOK_2) {
                indexA++;
                indexB = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    static class Piece {
        Pieces piece;
        Team team;

        Piece(Pieces piece, Team team) {
            this.piece = piece;
            this.team = team;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return piece.name().substring(0, 1);
        }
    }

    enum Pieces {
        ROOK_1, KNIGHT_1, BISHOP_1, KING, QUEEN, BISHOP_2, KNIGHT_2, ROOK_2,
        PAWN_1, PAWN_2, PAWN_3, PAWN_4, PAWN_5, PAWN_6, PAWN_7, PAWN_8
    }

    enum Team {
        BLACK, WHITE
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        for (Piece[] row : board) {
            for (Piece piece : row) {
                if (piece != null) string.append("%s ".formatted(piece));
                else string.append("  ");
            }
            string.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return string.toString();
    }
}
```

Output.
I realize, now, that the single character is obviously not the best way to represent the pieces—just an example.

```
R K B K Q B K R 
P P P P P P P P 
                
                
                
                
P P P P P P P P 
R K B K Q B K R
```